# How to make simple python UDP socket server?

Tags: python, django, websocket, udp, django-channels

I am trying to make a python socket server based on UDP.

The point is that we need to receive data from the Java client socket server and the python UDP protocol socket server must throw JSON data to React in the front.

I have the level of knowledge to make a simple UDP chat server, so I'm worried a lot now.
I am currently reading the django channels official documentation.
Does django-channeles provide easy configuration to use UDP protocol as well?

Answer (score 0):

There is a specification for raw UDP [in the docs](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/1.x/asgi/udp.html). UDP is not reliable as some of the data may be lost, so it is not widely used. If you must use it, you have to implement a UDP consumer based on the specification using the websocket consumers as a template